# loading content of XML file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xelement

So i have a XML file that looks like this.

```
  <recept id="1" sort="vardag">
    <!-- namn och portioner förekommer endast en gång i varje respektive element-->
    <namn>Pannkaka</namn>
    <portioner>4 portioner</portioner>
    <!--elementet ingrediens inehåller PCDATA och ett underelement dvs mangd
  och kan förekomma minst 1 eller flera gånger-->

      <ingrediens>
        Ägg<mangd> 3 st</mangd>
      </ingrediens>
      <ingrediens>
        Mjölk<mangd> 10 dl</mangd>
      </ingrediens>
      <ingrediens>
        Mjöl<mangd> 3 dl</mangd>
      </ingrediens>
      <ingrediens>
        Salt<mangd> En nypa</mangd>
      </ingrediens>
      <ingrediens>
        Matfett<mangd> 2 msk matolja eller smör</mangd>
      </ingrediens>

    <!--elementet tillredning kan endast förekomma en gång i elementet recept och
  innehåller PCDATA-->
    <tillredning>
      <steg>Ta fram en lagom stor bunke</steg>
      <steg>Smält smöret i en kastrull</steg>
      <steg>Vispa ihop ägg, mjölk, mjöl och saltet</steg>
      <steg>Låt smöret svalna en smula och blanda sen det i smeten</steg>
      <steg>Stek gyllenbruna i stekpanna på medelvärme</steg>
    </tillredning>
  </recept>
```

Now when i search on ID i want everything between  to be loaded.
Ive currently just added them by + but then if a subcategory has more then one it only loads one of them.

```
    private void buttonSök_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var v = (from x in el.Descendants("recept")
                 where x.Attribute("id").Value.ToLower() == textBoxID.Text.ToLower()
                 select x).FirstOrDefault();

        if (v == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Finns inte!");
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = v.Element("namn").Value + "\r\n" + v.Element("portioner").Value + "\r\n" + v.Element("ingredienser").Value +"\r\n" + v.Element("tillredning").Value;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a method similar to the below for extracting the ingredients:

```
private static string ExtractIngredients(XElement v)
{
    var ingredients = v
        .Elements("ingrediens")
        .Select(e => 
            e.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value +
            ": " +
            e.Element("mangd").Value);

    return String.Join("\r\n", ingredients);
}
```

Here, you use the fact that the ingredient names are XML text nodes, and refer to them as separate children of the *"ingrediens"* node.